# jQuery check divs has a class and unwrap if no other class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two `div's` and what I am trying to do is loop through all the divs to check if the `div` has a class `jsn-bootstrap3`, I'm also trying to check to see if the div has any other classes, if it doesn't then I'd like to remove the `jsn-bootstrap3` div so that the child content is whats left.

```
<div class="jsn-bootstrap3">
    <div class="wrapper">
        Div one
    </div>
</div>
<div class="jsn-bootstrap3 block">
    <div class="wrapper">
        Div two
    </div>
</div>


$('div').each(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass()) {
        console.log($(this));
        var class_name = $(this).attr('jsn-bootstrap3');
        console.log(class_name);
    }
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/whd02a9u/1/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like

```
$('div.jsn-bootstrap3').removeClass('jsn-bootstrap3').filter(function () {
    return $.trim(this.className.replace('jsn-bootstrap3', '')) == ''
}).contents().unwrap();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/77mzko13/)

- use the class selector to find div's with class jsn-bootstrap3 because we are not goint to do anything with others
- use filter() to filter out div's with any other class
- use unwrap() with contents() to remove the wrapping div

Comment: This is almost there, I was hoping to remove `.jsn-bootstrap3` from the other div too

Comment: No need to replace the class again as it's already removed.
`$('div.jsn-bootstrap3').removeClass('jsn-bootstrap3').filter(function () {
    return $.trim(this.className) == ''
}).contents().unwrap();`

Comment: @vikram Your code removed the class .jsn-bootstrap3 Did you check that?

Comment: @RajivRisi look at the first comment

Comment: @RajivRisi Read his comment to this answer.